# copy() & getcwd() works locally, not online

Tags: php

This line of code works for me locally:

```
$copythumb = copy($externalsource, getcwd().'\\img\\covers\\'.$id.'thumb.jpg');
if (!$copythumb) {echo 'Couldn\'t add thumbnail';}
```

But when I upload it to my server I just get "Couldn't add thumbnail" and it's not copied.
I've tried to change `\\img\\covers\\` to `/img/covers/` with no luck.
Ive' also messed around with `dirname(realpath(__FILE__))` and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Local:

```
echo getcwd(); //returns D:\Server\www\project
```

Server:

```
echo getcwd(); //returns /storage/content/xx/xxxxxx/xxx.com/public_html/project
```

Would be really thankful if someone could provide any help!

Comment: Do you have write access to that path?

Comment: Keep in mind that when running in the webserver, it runs as a different user.

Comment: If you are in a shared web host there may be some restrictions on what you can and cannot do. Not to mention that you need to make sure you have permissions to access and write to the selected directory

Comment: I should have write access. I've tried to set it to 777 and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

change your img or cover directory permission

```
<?php
// Read and write for owner, nothing for everybody else
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0600);

// Read and write for owner, read for everybody else
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0644);

// Everything for owner, read and execute for others
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);

// Everything for owner, read and execute for owner's group
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0750);
?>
```

Comment: I should have write access. I've tried to set it to 777 and it doesn't work.